# JS removeEventListener doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, listener, onclicklistener

I have a bunch of divs(current_items). Each div has a button - "remove div" (remove_buttons).
Each button has a click listener. After clicking on any button I need all listeners for all buttons to be removed. But `removeEventListener` doesn't work. Do you know why? Please let me know.

My JS code is:

```
var current_items = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_post_wrap'),
remove_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_remove_button');

// This is a function for click listeners. 
function removeItem(object1, obeject2, object3, index)
{
    return function ()
    {
        //Some code which removes divs from DOM. 
        //And then removes all listeners:

        for (let i = 0; i < current_items.length; i++)
        {
            remove_buttons[i].removeEventListener("click", removeItem);
        }
    }
}

// Here I create my click listeners for each button. 
for (let i = 0; i < current_items.length; i++)
{
    remove_buttons[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem(current_items[i], ids_list[i], types_list[i], i));
}
```

Comment: I think I can see your problem. Remember the **removeItem()** function *returns another function*. This means that you need to place brackets **()** at the end of your code like this: **removeItem(current_items[i], ids_list[i], types_list[i], i)()**. Hope this helps.

Comment: This could be simplified by delegating your click handler to the document.body and not worrying about removing the event handlers. This would allow you to have a single click handler and not mess with looping etc.

Comment: Hello @Joachim, thank you very much for your help, but unfortunately it hasn't helped. It started to infinitely load the page after clicking. But Ali Nauman below gave a correct answer and it helped, so no worries, now I am alright. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In order for `removeEventListener` to work, you need to pass the reference to the function you added as the event listener. You are not saving the return value of the `removeItem` function call when you're adding the event listeners - you're just passing the event listener there, and on removing, you're passing a reference to the `removeItem` factory function, which was never added as an event listener, hence why this is not working.

When creating the event listeners, you need to store them somewhere, and pass them to `removeEventListener`. Something like this should work:

```js
const current_items = document.getElementsByClassName("cart_post_wrap");
const remove_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("cart_remove_button");
const eventListeners = [];

function removeItem(object1, obeject2, object3, index) {
  return function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < current_items.length; i++) {
      remove_buttons[i].removeEventListener("click", eventListeners[i]);
    }
  };
}

for (let i = 0; i < current_items.length; i++) {
  // Save a reference to the event listener
  const listener = removeItem(current_items[i], ids_list[i], types_list[i], i);
  eventListeners.push(listener);
  remove_buttons[i].addEventListener("click", listener);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeaaaah my dear savior. I've never seen this type of explanation on the internet. Everybody says that you just need to use a name of a function for the listener to find it then when you want to remove it, but it didn't helped. Meanwhile your answer is great and it has helped! Good luck Mr. Ali Nauman!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `remove_buttons[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem(current_items[i], ids_list[i], types_list[i], i));` is not adding the `removeItem` function as the event listener; it's calling the `removeItem` function and adding whatever it returns as the event listener; in this case, an in-lined function with `return function () { ... }`.

Later, you try to remove the `removeItem` function as the event listener, but as explained above, it was not added as the event listener in the first place.

If you're planning on removing the elements from the DOM anyway, as your comment in the code suggests, there's no point in removing the buttons' click event listeners: if they are gone from the DOM, they can no longer be clicked. Forget about removing the click event listeners, and instead have much cleaner code as a result.